# How to access cells in a simple grid Layout (Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My grid Layout looks like this :

```
height = 5
width = 5
for i in range(height): #Rows
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        b = Entry(root, text="")
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)
```

How do I access each cell? to write in it, or to acces the data that has been written in it while the programm is running?
Because the variable `b` is only the 25th cell.

Comment: You should store each widget in a list or dictionary before adding them to the grid. This way you can access them all without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the parent window to get all of the slaves, and you can use `grid_info()` on a widget that is managed by `grid` to find out what row and what column it is in.

That's pretty cumbersome, however. The simplest thing is to store the widgets in a data structure which lets you easily access the widgets. A dictionary works well for this, with the keys being a tuple of the row and column.

For example:

```
widgets = {}
for i in range(height): #Rows
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        b = Entry(root, text="")
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)
        widgets[(i,j)] = b
```

With that, you can reference any widget by row and column. For example:

```
widgets[(2,3)].insert("end", "Hello, world")
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I never would have thought of that ! :P